# how to fix the digital envelope routines unsupported in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm facing an issue while building my Angular application, and I'm seeking assistance to resolve it. During the build process, I'm encountering the following error.

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:68
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at context.callback (/Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /Users/Desktop/Apps/project/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:71
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}




"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "npm run env -s && ng build --prod",
    "start": "npm run env -s && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "serve:sw": "npm run build -s && npx http-server ./dist -p 4200",
    "lint": "ng lint && stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\" --syntax scss && htmlhint \"src\" --config .htmlhintrc",
    "test": "npm run env -s && ng test",
    "test:ci": "npm run env -s && npm run lint -s && ng test --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "e2e": "npm run env -s && ng e2e",
    "docs": "hads ./docs -o",
    "env": "ngx-scripts env npm_package_version",
    "generate": "ng generate",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node local.js",
    "server": "node local.js",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:ssr",
    "serve:prerender": "node static.js",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  }
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/service-worker": "^11.2.14",
  "@capacitor/android": "^2.5.0",
  "@capacitor/cli": "^2.5.0",
  "@capacitor/core": "^2.5.0",
  "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
  "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
  "@nguniversal/common": "^11.2.1",
  "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.2.1",
  "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
  "@ngxs/store": "^3.8.0",
  "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "~9.0.0",
  "ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.2",
  "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
  "ag-grid-enterprise": "^21.2.2",
  "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
  "bootstrap-utilities": "^4.1.3",
  "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
  "core-js": "^3.23.3",
  "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
  "d3": "^4.13.0",
  "date-fns": "^2.17.0",
  "domino": "^2.1.3",
  "echarts": "^5.4.3",
  "exceljs": "^4.2.0",
  "express": "^4.15.2",
  "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
  "lodash": "^4.17.21",
  "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
  "lzwcompress": "^1.1.0",
  "net": "^1.0.2",
  "ng-zorro-antd": "^11.4.2",
  "ngx-echarts": "^7.1.0",
  "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.1.0",
  "places.js": "^1.19.0",
  "postcode-validator": "^3.5.3",
  "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
  "sockjs-client": "^1.3.0",
  "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
  "sweetalert2": "^10.16.11",
  "tslib": "^2.0.0",
  "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
  "xml2js": "^0.5.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.19",
  "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
  "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.14",
  "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
  "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^4.2.0",
  "@ngx-rocket/scripts": "^5.2.3",
  "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.8.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.18",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
  "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
  "@types/node": "^14.18.63",
  "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
  "hads": "^1.7.0",
  "htmlhint": "^0.11.0",
  "https-proxy-agent": "^2.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
  "karma": "~6.4.2",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
  "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "stylelint": "~10.1.0",
  "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "~3.3.0",
  "stylelint-config-standard": "~18.3.0",
  "stylelint-scss": "~3.9.0",
  "ts-loader": "^5.4.5",
  "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "~4.0.8",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
}
```

The error is related to digital envelope routines and seems to be unsupported.
The build is using Webpack and Angular CLI.
The project is configured with Node.js v18.13.0.
I have already tried updating Node.js, reinstalling packages.